# Which features are allowed for company store accounts and not individual?

Tags: windows-8

To publish an app in the Windows 8 store, you must have a store account. There are two types of accounts: individual and company. These accounts are NOT identical. Some declarations in your app's manifest cannot be used if your have an individual account.

Which declarations cannot be used if your have an individual account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a  [full list of differences between the individual and company accounts for the Windows Store](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/09/18/what-is-the-difference-between-a-company-vs-individual-account-for-the-windows-store.aspx) that I've been gathering.

To address your specific question, there are 3 capabilities that can be used only by applications submitted from a company account.  (This is documented at [App capability declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx)).  They are:

1. **enterpriseAuthentication**. Uses your Windows credentials for
   access to a corporate intranet.
2. **sharedUserCertificates**. Allows the use of software and hardware certificates or a smart card to identify users in the app.
3. **documentsLibrary**. Allows access to a user's documents library, including the capability to add, change, or delete files.

Answer (score 0):

- Company accounts require verification.
- Individual accounts don't require the verification process. And it can't submit desktop applications.

Read for more information on this website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868184.aspx

Comment: Update: Here an overview what you can do -> individual account (detail text): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657972.aspx