# How deploy intranet WCF-service for Windows 8 store application

Tags: wcf, deployment, windows-8, windows-store-apps

We are developing a desktop Windows 8 application, that work with WCF-service. We want enable work with Azure WCF-service and with WCF-service in local network(choosingly). Application will be publish in Windows Store. 
What the best practise deploy WCF-service on local server of company?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand what you want. Let's pretend the Azure part is not an option. How can a Windows Store App use a local service (WCF or not)? That's the fundamental question.

Here's the answer(s):

1. First, a Windows Store App cannot access intranet services unless it has private network access declared in its manifest. It looks like this:

[image]

2. Second, in order to use private networks in your manifest **and** get accepted into the Windows Store, you must be a company publisher and not an individual. More on this is discussed in this SO question: [Which features are allowed for company store accounts and not individual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035869/which-features-are-allowed-for-company-store-accounts-and-not-individual)
3. Third, a local service cannot be mistakenly thought of as *localhost*. To this end, *localhost* is not available to Windows Store Apps, unless they are side-loaded (which means they are manually installed and not delivered through the Windows Store at all). To access *localhost*, you can enable loopback, but, as I stated, this disqualifies you from the Windows Store. There's more on this here: [How does Windows 8 Loop Back work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770863/how-does-windows-8-loop-back-work)
4. Forth, because you are talking about a service, you might want to authenticate the user. This is accomplished using enterprise authentication (just like in number 1) only a few checkboxes higher. And it has the same restrictions as private networks.
5. Fifth, you are not asking this, but to be clear, local access does not mean you can speak to a local SQL server. The reason for this is because the SQL namespace is not part of WinRT or .Net for WinRT. Windows Store Apps are intended to be service-based apps.

And, that's about it. I think you are good if you follow that.

It doesn't sound like you are talking about a pure enterprise-play, but it might be interesting to you to read through some of the strategies for enterprise developers: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-apps-whats-enterprise-to-do.html

**As for deploying WCF, there's nothing special just because a Windows Store App is accessing it. So for deployment, just use vanilla techniques you are already using. :) That's it.**

Best of luck!